# HTML 5 canvas (сохранение картинки)

Tags: post, php, web-camera, html5

Есть на странице canvas, куда делается скриншот с web камеры. Т.е. у нас есть полученное с камеры изображение. Как его отправить на сервер и сохранить в jpg?

Comment: Искали? Первая ссылка: http://www.py-my.ru/post/509e3150bbddbd2f44000006#!

Comment: Ну почти, только у меня php. Данные отправляю, получаю и из них не могу сделать imagecreatefromstring. Такое ощущение что дописываются какие-то заголовки, если их обрезать, то imagecreatefromstring ок, но изображение получатеся пустым.

Comment: м?

   $file = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $file);
    $file = base64_decode($file);  
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($file);

Comment: да, оно ()